# Applescript: Need Help Resolving - Can't Get every file of said folder?

Tags: applescript

With the help of some users on this form I was able to create this script below which lets you choose a folder then choose which folders within the folder you want to rsync into a OneDrive Backup Folder.

Basically were migrating from a on site network storage to OneDrive for Business and want to create a script that as easy as possible for our users.

The issue I have is I dont want the users to be able to choose the original folder, I want to set the variable up front.

In the script I use:

```
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please Choose The Root of Your H Drive Or The Folder That Looks Like:    " & userName & "$")
```

If I use:

```
set theFolder to "/Volumes/MYERSMI5$/"
```

I get "Can't Get every file of said folder" error message.

How Do I set the `theFolder` for this script ahead of time instead of asking the user to pick the folder?

```
set OuserName to do shell script "whoami"
set userName to do shell script "echo " & OuserName & " | tr a-z A-Z"

tell application "Finder"
   if not (disk userName exists) then
       mount volume "SMB Server/" & userName & "$"
   end if

 delay 2

   set theDialogText to "
       - Mac H-Drive Migration Tool -

This Application Will Migrate a Copy of Your H Drive Data
to your OneDrive for Buisness Folder Locally on Your Mac

Migration Backup Location: 
/Users/" & OuserName & "/OneDrive Folder/H-Drive Migration Backup

** Important **    
In the Next Window Please Choose 
The Root Folder of Your H Drive
The Drive Label Should Look Like:    " & userName & "$"

   display dialog theDialogText

   set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please Choose The Root of Your H Drive Or The Folder That Looks Like:    " & userName & "$")  

   do shell script "mkdir -p ~/'OneDrive Folder'/'H-Drive Migration Backup'"

   set HDriveBackupFolder to ((path to home folder as text) & "OneDrive Folder:H-Drive Migration Backup")

   set AppName to "OneDrive.app"

   tell application "Finder" to set Answer_ to exists application file ((path to applications folder as string) & AppName)
   if Answer_ is false then

       beep
       beep
       beep
       beep
       beep

   end if

   delay 1.5

   tell application "Finder"
       activate
       set theFolderNames to name of folders of theFolder
       set theChosenNames to (choose from list theFolderNames with prompt "Choose Which Folders to Backup, Please Hold Down The ⌘ Key To Choose Multiple Folders " with multiple selections allowed)
       if (theChosenNames is false) then return

       set HDriveBackupFolder to ((path to home folder as text) & "OneDrive Folder:H-Drive Migration Backup")
   end tell

   repeat with thisName in theChosenNames

       tell application "Terminal"

           do script ("rsync -avpz --delete " & (quoted form of POSIX path of ((theFolder as text) & thisName)) & space & (quoted form of POSIX path of HDriveBackupFolder)

       end tell
   end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: The Finder does not accept POSIX paths (slash separated) but HFS paths (colon separated) and AppleScript alias specifiers. The shell accepts only POSIX paths, nothing else. You have to pass the proper path types.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> "How Do I set the `theFolder` for this script ahead of time instead of asking the user to pick the folder?"

Also, just prior to that, you said:

> If I use:
>
> ```
>    set theFolder to "/Volumes/MYERSMI5$/"
> ```
>
> I get "Can't Get every file of said folder" error message.

---

First, lets address setting the *value* of the `theFolder` *variable*. It should be as follows:

```
set theFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/MYERSMI5$/"
```

I assume the error is being thrown at the following point in the *code*:

```
   tell application "Finder"
       activate
       set theFolderNames to name of folders of theFolder
```

Change `set theFolderNames to name of folders of theFolder` to:

```
set theFolderNames to name of folders of container theFolder
```

To test this, I mounted a *volume* named `MYERSMI5$` at `/Volumes/` and created some folders within `/Volumes/MYERSMI5$/`. Then running the following *code*:

```
set theFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/MYERSMI5$/"
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set theFolderNames to name of folders of container theFolder
    set theChosenNames to (choose from list theFolderNames with prompt "Choose Which Folders to Backup, Please Hold Down The ⌘ Key To Choose Multiple Folders " with multiple selections allowed)
    if (theChosenNames is false) then return
end tell
```

It produced a list box, containing the names of the folders I created at that location, to choose from.

I did not try to run the entire block of *code* you included in your question, so if you're having other issues, you'll need to follow up after making the changes mentioned in my answer. There are good reasons why questions involving debugging *code* should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

You may also want to review the [Variables and Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html) section in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1).